# Adult son moved out but left belongings behind

Tags: property, family-law, eviction

my adult son 28 has moved in with his girlfriend and her parents and has left the majority of his belongings in my house, How long do I have to give him to remove them and what can I do if he doesn't remove them ( can i dispose of them ) ?

Comment: How much do you value your relationship with your son, and how do you think he'd react to you throwing out his stuff, even if you're legally justified in doing so?

Comment: unfortunately our relationship has broken down due to his girlfriend I am looking to downsize in the near future for health reasons . i want him to have the chance to come and get them but I need to know what my options are if he doesn't .

Comment: Ownership does not end by leaving something behind unless it does - it's complicated, get a lawyer.

Comment: How did your son's girlfriend ruin your relationship with your son?

Answer (score 2):

### It is likely you are a [bailee](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/bailee)

A bailee is a person who is entrusted with the property of another without transfer of ownership. A bailee is responsible for the care and protection of that property and its return when requested.

You must act reasonably with respect to the property and take reasonable precautions to protect it. If you store it in a damp cellar and it gets dated, you are liable for that damage.

It is not reasonable for you to keep it indefinitely. If you wrote to your son giving him a reasonable time for its removal (say 6 weeks) after which you tell him you will dispose of it, that’s probably fine. Even better, pay a lawyer to write the letter if, as you say, the relationship has broken down irreparably. Of course, letters from lawyers can *cause* irreparable breakdowns.